# How to use categorical variable to color geom_path

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a question that probably has a simple answer, but I can't figure it out. I'm making a graphic using ggplot2, specifically geom_path(). The path is colored according to a categorical variable `intersects`, which takes the value TRUE if the path crosses a certain polygon and FALSE otherwise (I assigned group=1 so the paths are not grouped by the variable).

It is working almost as I would like it to, except that the color is applied to the following path segment instead of the preceding segment. For example,  if observation i = TRUE, and i + 1 = FALSE, the resulting path is colored TRUE between positions i, i+1; and FALSE between positions i+1, i+2. 
I would like the path between positions i-1, i to be colored TRUE, and i, i+1 to be FALSE.

```
# Create polygon.
boundary_x <- c(640343.419, 640341.452, 640339.242, 640337.471, 640339.538, 640341.603)
boundary_y <- c(4858742.348, 4858733.404, 4858722.512, 4858722.853, 4858732.737, 4858742.649)
boundary <- data.frame(x = boundary_x, y = boundary_y)

# Sample data
x <- c(640338.007929366, 640338.077929366, 640338.857929366, 640338.867929366, 640338.459933366, 640338.407929366, 640338.174617366, 640338.139168366, 640338.070599366, 640337.747929366, 640337.847929366, 640338.439430366, 640338.777929366, 640338.877929366, 640339.444178366, 640339.557929366, 640340.247929366, 640340.927929366, 640340.977929366, 640341.107929366, 640341.157929366, 640341.427929366, 640341.477929366, 640341.807929366, 640341.847929366, 640342.427929366, 640342.642404366, 640342.867436366, 640342.878517366, 640343.116330366, 640343.097929366, 640343.007929366, 640342.387929366, 640341.929667366, 640341.837929366, 640339.927929366, 640339.847929366, 640336.427929366, 640335.717929366, 640335.057929366, 640334.967929366, 640334.681813366, 640334.208384366, 640334.172648366, 640334.417929366, 640334.587929366, 640334.777929366, 640334.987929366, 640334.925775366, 640338.257929366, 640338.187929366, 640338.057929366, 640338.077929366, 640338.077929366, 640340.200274366, 640341.037929366, 640341.114123366, 640341.187929366, 640341.237929366)
y <- c(4858731.28088173, 4858731.24088173, 4858730.80088173, 4858730.79088173, 4858728.57674273, 4858728.30088173, 4858727.05816773, 4858726.86768973, 4858726.36255673, 4858722.41088173, 4858722.03088173, 4858721.55321173, 4858721.29088173, 4858721.27088173, 4858721.16125073, 4858721.13088173, 4858721.06088173, 4858720.89088173, 4858720.90088173, 4858720.86088173, 4858720.85088173, 4858720.83088173, 4858720.84088173, 4858721.10088173, 4858721.14088173, 4858722.17088173, 4858722.50853873, 4858722.94242373, 4858722.98987973, 4858725.39572673, 4858725.44088173, 4858725.57088173, 4858725.69088173, 4858725.44266973, 4858725.40088173, 4858721.90088173, 4858721.81088173, 4858721.76088173, 4858721.93088173, 4858722.11088173, 4858722.18088173, 4858722.67533273, 4858723.32189973, 4858723.40558473, 4858727.23088173, 4858727.71088173, 4858728.14088173, 4858728.61088173, 4858730.42873273, 4858728.23088173, 4858727.62088173, 4858726.41088173, 4858726.32088173, 4858726.32088173, 4858726.02508273, 4858726.13088173, 4858726.13140073, 4858726.19088173, 4858726.23088173)
intersects <- c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE)
df <- data.frame(x = x, y = y, intersects = intersects)

# Plot
ggplot() + 
  geom_polygon(data = boundary, aes(x, y)) + 
  geom_path(data = df, aes(x, y, col = intersects, group = 1)) + 
  geom_point(data = df, aes(x, y, col = intersects)) + 
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(640334, 640343), ylim = c(4858721, 4858731))
```

When you view the plot, you'll see the blue segments represent intersects = TRUE, and they occur right after the path crosses the polygon. I'd like to shift the color back, so to speak, so the segment actually crossing the polygon is colored.

*I'm new around here and don't have enough reputation to post an image..sorry!*

Comment: Please provide your code.

Comment: Added some sample code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is that you assign the colour (through the column `intersects`) to the points, not the lines that will actually carry the colour. `ggplot2` considers each point to be the start of a line, which is then coloured, while you consider them to be the end of a line to be coloured.

You could, of course, just change your definition of the column `intersection` to go along with how ggplot2 handles the situation. Alternatively, you can modify the column when creating the plot using `lead()` from the `dplyr` package:

```
ggplot() + 
  geom_polygon(data = boundary, aes(x, y)) + 
  geom_path(data = df, aes(x, y, col = dplyr::lead(intersects, default = FALSE), group = 1)) + 
  geom_point(data = df, aes(x, y, col = intersects)) + 
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(640334, 640343), ylim = c(4858721, 4858731)) +
  labs(col = "intersects")
```

[image]

The function `lead()` simply takes a vector and shifts its contents by one element to the left:

```
dplyr::lead(1:3)
## [1]  2  3 NA
```

Obviously, the function cannot know what to do with the last element of the vector, but you can provide the value that you want:

```
dplyr::lead(1:3, default = 7)
## [1] 2 3 7
```

There is also an analogous function `dplyr::lag()` that shifts in the other direction.